# Maven build failing

Tags: maven-3

I am new to Java/Coding and release builds etc. Am faced with a problem currently and would appreciate any pointers to help solve. When I try to run a build using Maven on a Mac it fails with the error below. However if I run the same build on a Windows OS it runs fine. Any pointers?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResource.isExisting(PlexusIoFileResource.java:126)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.asArchiveEntry(AbstractArchiver.java:296)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.asArchiveEntry(AbstractArchiver.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:448)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```

Comment: Possible Option 1) Windows is not case sensitive, Unix file system is case sensitive. Able to resolve if we know the maven command which you are executing and also please post the logs of both Windows and Mac OS.